# Gerber X1 to Gerber X2

Tags: pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers, gerber

I have gerber files from a client. Their extensions are: .fph, .fpl, .pho, .rep, .drl, .lst, .dxf. Of these, I know .drl are the drill files and .dxf is the mechanical drawing. Also, there is a .fph and .fpl file for every layer. I need to convert this to Gerber X2. For this, I need the board attributes. As this gerber is primitive to X2, I know the attributes are lost when generating these files but still there must be some way these attributes are communicated to the manufacturer. Where can I find these attributes in these files? After finding these attributes, how to generate the X2?

Comment: As I already explained in my answer to your previous question: no. They're lost. Lost means lost. You can't make up attributes out of thin air.

Comment: "_I need the board attributes_" ... what "_attributes_" exactly are you after?